# What is this military radio?

Tags: transceiver, history, military-surplus

Please help me identify this piece of equipment. It looks military spec, but don't know anything about it.

I want to look up some history about what it was used for.

[image: Front]
[image: Controls]
[image: Handset]
[image: Label]

[Here are more photos.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/xepC1aYx2FJP5h5t5)

Comment: Have you checked the back for an ID plate?

Comment: Hello Leo, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com! Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help pages](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) to get the most from the site. I have edited your question slightly to clarify it.

Comment: no i havent is that the back of the device or the back of the removable plate? if you mean the back of the device it will have to wait until next thursday. any piticular location would be helpful

Comment: The plate could be anywhere: top, sides, or back. We cannot tell you where it is

Comment: I've edited your question to embed the images — this is because questions should (ideally) be meaningful without needing to follow links to other sites, which could change or break and are not as quick to read.

Comment: So there is no ID plate *anywhere* on the outside? That's really odd. Those C.R.E.H. marks are just inspection stamps.

Answer (score 2):

The construction does not look appropriate for military service. Coast guard, Civil Aviation, emergency services or industry looks more likely. Photographs of the interior may yield more clues. A fixed squelch control may be a clue this was designed for VHF or UHF. It was not common to totally enclose radio equipment without ventilation so this may only contain the remote control circuit.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, except this is painted OD (olive drab).

Comment: Apologies for the late reply not been online for a while i do have more pictures of the device/radio hopefully these circuit photos and i did find possibly a check mark on the underside of the lid will include photos shortly

Comment: Please check the photo link at the top